# Curl and grep status code and content of the file

Tags: curl, grep

Is there way to curl and grep for an expression while matching a first line (which contains status code) using grep? (Without saving the result of the curl on a file or a variable.)

I am thinking some thing like this but using grep -

```
curl -is "http://example.com/test.html" | awk 'NR == 1 || /'"JOB_STATUS"'/'
```

using maybe head and grep

```
  head -n 1 and grep -E "exp[ab]"
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the awk you have?

Comment: The awk command works but wanted to do the same with grep because I am using grep flags like -A -B etc on my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your curl output looks something like this:

```
Status:200
something ... something
JOB_STATUS
```

you can use:

```
curl ... | egrep "Status:|JOB_STATUS"
```

to get the first line and the JOB_STATUS line.

Or, as you have something against awk, maybe sed, like this:

```
curl ... | sed -ne '1p' -e '/JOB_STATUS/p'
```

I think you need to show the output of your curl command and explain what's wrong with your awk...

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -is "http"//example.com/test.html" | head -1 | grep -E 'exp[ab]'
```

Comment: That does not work. head -1 returns the first line and this line is passed to grep. I want the rest of content to be passed through grep.
I can do something like "grep -E "^HTTP/1.1|exp[ab]" to get what I want, but just wanted to know if that was possible.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you post sample input and desired output?