# Using tilde or caret with 'git ls-remote'

Tags: git

I'm using `git ls-remote` to get commit hashes of branches in a repository of which I don't have a clone.

```
git ls-remote ssh://gitosis@myServer/myRepo.git master
```

I'm interested being about specify a commit like `master~` and use `git ls-remote` to figure out what it's commit hash is.

Does Git support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Git support this?

No, as I explained in "[Show git logs for range of commits on remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5959161/6309)"

> it works on ref patterns (head, tags, branches, ...), not with revs

You would need to fetch first, in order to check `origin/master~`.

---

[Intended use](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512652/ajwood):

> A custom, perhaps hackish, application.
> It's a mechanism for users to issue requests to the system for building and installing specific versions of software.
> It supports `build_request SomeProject someBranch`.
> For completeness, I think it should support a request for `someBranch~`.

I suppose it would be possible then to set up a kind of web service, a listener able to interpret a user query and do the `git log master~` on that common server.
That listener wouldn't have anything to do with git.

Comment: Shoot.. I was hoping to avoid having to clone an entire repository ust to get a silly little commit hash :(

Comment: @ajwood but you don't have to fetch the *all* repo, only the branch you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6369199/6309

Comment: Even still.. `fetch` is way slower than `ls-remote`

Comment: @ajwood I agree. Why do you want to get that remote `master~` SHA1?

Comment: A custom, perhaps hackish, application. It's a mechanism for users to issue requests to the system for building and installing specific versions of software. It supports `build_request SomeProject someBranch`. For completeness, I think it should support a request for `someBranch~`.

Comment: @ajwood would it be possible then to set up a kind of web service, a listener able to interpret a user query and do the `git log master~` on that common server? That listener wouldn't have anything to do with git.

Comment: that's a good idea! I've been thinking about a world-writeable clone that anyone could `cd` into for a `fetch/log` and what kind of trouble that could get me into..

Comment: Maybe the intended use would be good to include in the question, and also the separate-service idea in the answer?

Comment: @jthill I will, I am commuting right now (train). I'll get to it in an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is hosted by Github a partial solution consists in using the REST API. It'd be possible to adjust the results by specifying values for `sha` , `per_page` and `page` parameters. The general pattern is

`https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPOSITORY/commits?per_page=NUMBER&sha=SHA_OR_NAME&page=NUMBER`

... e.g. SHA of commits in `develop..develop~20` range of `simelo/skycoin-hardware-wallet` repository can be retrieved from [the URL](https://api.github.com/repos/skycoin/hardware-wallet/commits?per_page=20&sha=develop) `https://api.github.com/repos/skycoin/hardware-wallet/commits?per_page=20&sha=develop`...

... whereas SHA of commits in `develop~15..develop~40` range of `simelo/skycoin-hardware-wallet` repository can be retrieved from [this URL](https://api.github.com/repos/skycoin/hardware-wallet/commits?per_page=15&sha=develop&page=2) `https://api.github.com/repos/skycoin/hardware-wallet/commits?per_page=15&sha=develop&page=2` followed by data extracted from [this one](https://api.github.com/repos/skycoin/hardware-wallet/commits?per_page=10&sha=develop&page=3) `https://api.github.com/repos/skycoin/hardware-wallet/commits?per_page=10&sha=develop&page=3`

For further instructions about how to get this done from the command line please consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375630/curl-and-grep-status-code-and-content-of-the-file).